# Practicing Index Notation proofs

Tags: index-notation

I am practicing proving things with index notation in order to get a good grasp of the way it works. One of the problems that I came up against is
$\nabla(\frac{1}{2}v^2) = \vec{v}\times(\nabla\times\vec{v})+(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)\vec{v}  $

You can write the right hand side as $\epsilon_{ijk}v_i\epsilon_{xyj}\partial_xv_y + v_i\partial_iv_k$ this comes down to $v_iv_i\partial_k - v_i\partial_iv_k + v_i\partial_iv_k$ the last two terms cancel so you are left with $\nabla v^2$ but where is the half?

Comment: I would advise starting on the right hand side...

Comment: Yes, it's normally better to start on the more complicated side for algebraic proofs.

Comment: I updated the question, I get most of it but not the half.